# thread synchronization c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a multi threaded application.

I am trying to synchronize / thread-safe it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Thread t = new Thread(()=>Met1(x));
   Monitor.Enter(t);
   t.start();
   Monitor.Exit(t);

   Thread t2 = new Thread(()=>Met2(x,y));
   Monitor.Enter(t2);
   t2.start();
   Monitor.Exit(t2);
}
```

However, the application is not thread-safe / synchronized.

Comment: There's a good intro to threading here: [`Albahari`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` must be done by thread themselves. In your code, this is done by the main thread in the process of setting up the two threads. Moreover, that needs to be a monitor of the same object, not two different objects like it is in your case.

To fix this, you need to move the `Enter`/`Exit` onto the thread into the delegate, and add a common object for the monitor, like this:

```
object mon = new object();
Thread t = new Thread(()=>{
    Monitor.Enter(mon);
    Met1(x);
    Monitor.Exit(mon);
});
Thread t2 = new Thread(()=>{
    Monitor.Enter(mon);
    Met2(x,y);
    Monitor.Exit(mon);
});
t.start();
t2.start();
```

Now the `t` thread would not be able to call `Met1` while `Met2` is going, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different monitors. If you want synchronization, use the same monitor. I also suggest using monitors on objects other than the threads (for example a new object by itself as a lock). Further, consider using the lock statement in C# which wraps the same code for you and takes care of other gotchas as well (exceptions for example).

```
object synchronizationLock = new object();
lock (synchronizationLock)
{
    // Place logic here
}
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight's response also points out that you need to enter/exit the monitor from the threads themselves. Consider his answer superior to mine.